# run bash loop for two files in two commands of one program

Tags: bash, shell, loops, unix

I am trying to run a program that uses two different files:

```
Program -command1 $file1 -command2 $file2
```

i have used the bash loop for one file successfully but when i use it as:

```
for file in *.ext
do
    Program -command1 $file -command2 $file
done
```

It runs the same one file for both commands, looping to second file and doing the same thing for that one.

what i need the program to run both files individually for each command under one program run.

Answer (score 0):

Dummy code, using `printf` to output three directory names, and use `xargs` to feed those names to `Program`, (actually to `echo` so the results are visible):

```
printf '%s\n' foo bar baz | 
xargs -I '{}' echo Program -command1 '{}'/Type1.ext -command2 '{}'/Type2.ext
```

Output:

```
Program -command1 foo/Type1.ext -command2 foo/Type2.ext
Program -command1 bar/Type1.ext -command2 bar/Type2.ext
Program -command1 baz/Type1.ext -command2 baz/Type2.ext
```

To actually run `Program`, replace "*foo bar baz* with the names of the actual directories, and omit the `echo`:

```
printf '%s\n' ....dir names go here... | 
xargs -I '{}' Program -command1 '{}'/Type1.ext -command2 '{}'/Type2.ext
```